# Java exec doesn't work in 64 bit Windows

Tags: java, tomcat, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

I am trying to run the following ffmpeg command using java exec call. It works well in a 32bit computer but in 64 bit computer it doesn't work. Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

When I try the same command in command prompt as admin it works. Here the target is to create a video file in the tomcat. But when I try as a normal user in commandprompt it didn't work. Can this be an issue with tomcat privileges ?

Comment: Can you get the output of the `exec` call?

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit JVM? If it works as admin but not as a normal user then of course it could be a problem with privileges. How are you running Tomcat?

Comment: Please paste the command

Comment: @madth3 - I cannot get the output of the exec command. I am running Tomcat using GUI but as the admin.

Comment: @Mister Smith- the command is "ffmepg -i video.aiv -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -vcodec copy combinedfile.mov"

Comment: @dinesh707 Can't get output of exec command?? Try [debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging). See: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=debug+tomcat) or [that](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) or even [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_%28software%29#Software_tracing) if you didn't know.

Comment: does the program work on 64-bit OS when executed as the user running tomcat on command prompt? are you providing all the necessary env dependencies to the process?

Comment: when i run the command in command prompt as admin it works. Else it doesnt. I think tomcat do not work as admin in 64 bit setting

Comment: @dinesh707: Is it 64bit Windows? Did you try to start Tomcat with admin privileges?

Comment: *"using java exec call"* Before you even spend time wondering about the differences between the 32 & 64 bit environments, read & implement **all** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Your comments make me think the code has not correctly handled the output, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

If its works as admin, but not as normal user then it is likely a problem with the privileges.

I strongly recommend to add some logging around the execution.

for example

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process convertProcess = runtime.exec(execProperties);

/** important; read the error stream before! invoke waitFor */
BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(convertProcess.getErrorStream()));
try {
    StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
         errorMessage.append(line);
         errorMessage.append("\n");
    }

    int returnValue = convertProcess.waitFor();
    if (returnValue != 0) {
         handleNonZeroReturnValue(returnValue)
    }
} finally {
   errorReader.close();
}
```

*I hope that helps you to "debug" the problem*